# "Invalid field" error in Visualforce page during package installation

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, package, unmanaged-package, package-install

I've created an unmanaged package that consists of:

- several fields for a Lead object,
- and one Visualforce page (Pages_Visited)

During the installation of this package I get the following error:
[image]

The mentioned field is certainly present in the package:
[image]

And the Pages_Visited Visualforce page works perfectly fine on my Developer org.
It references the field like this:

```
<span id="gaconnector_pages_visited_list">{!lead.zuevsoftware__Pages_visited__c}</span>
```

I've tried installing this package on two orgs, one of them completely clean (no custom fields, no Apex triggers, nothing custom).
And both times I received the same error.

**What could be causing this problem?**

Comment: Might be due to `namespace` if its a managed package.

Comment: @RCS it's a managed package

Comment: Just remove the namespace before custom field and try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be namespace issue:
Try replacing to below syntax:

```
<span id="gaconnector_pages_visited_list"><apex:outputField value="{!lead.Pages_visited__c}" /> </span>
```